# Insert Static Nodes in XML with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google App Script which generates XML from Google Sheet data. Each row of the sheet is an Athlete. In the XML file, I want to insert a static (i.e. not connected to a Sheet) set of nodes at the beginning.

Example:

```
<MEET>

<CLASSES>
    <CLASS>
        <NAME>Track</NAME>
    </CLASS>
    <CLASS>
        <NAME>Field</NAME>
    </CLASS>
</CLASSES>
<EVENTS>
    <EVENT>
        <NAME>Run</NAME>
    </EVENT>
    <EVENT>
        <NAME>Throw</NAME>
    </EVENT>
    <EVENT>
        <NAME>Jump</NAME>
    </EVENT>
</EVENTS>

<ATHLETES>
  <ATHLETE>
    <NAME>Joe Smith</NAME>
    <ADDRESS>123 Main St, Anytown, NY 12121</ADDRESS>
    <EMAIL>joe@smith.com</EMAIL>
    <PHONE>518-555-1234</PHONE>
    <EMERGENCYNAME>Jane Smith</EMERGENCYNAME>
    <EMERGENCYPHONE>518-555-5678</EMERGENCYPHONE>
    <CLASS>Track</CLASS>
  </ATHLETE>
</ATHLETES>

</MEET>
```

In this example, the root node is `MEET` and has numerous `ATHLETE` nodes added to it, based on the rows of the Google Sheet. However, the `CLASSES` and `EVENTS` will never change. I do want to be able to access them in the data though.

How do I insert these nodes before my dynamic content, within the root node?

Comment: @I'-'I kind of irrelevant as it functions as-is. I need to add something to it which I’ve never done.

Comment: You'll get better answers on Stack Overflow if you can show an example of what you have tried. I understand you haven't done this before, so take a peek at the XmlService docs and try something, then if it doesn't work post the code and get help with it. Approaches to try are either using createElement() to dynamically create you static elements, or using parse() to parse your "template" xml from a string.

Comment: @CameronRoberts I ended up just putting those elements in a separate sheet (not attached to the input form) and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new Google Sheet for those elements, pulled them in same way as others.